# Strange error after MySQL migration - Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

We just upgraded our MySQL and now I get an error about the GUID then I get an error (Unexpected connection state. When using a wrapping provider ensure that the StateChange event is implemented on the wrapped DbConnection.) if I refresh and wathever I do.
It seems it has to do with Entity Framework and MySQL.

Current version : Ver 8.0.29 for Win64 on x86_64

Thanks,
Philippe

Comment: You can find previous questions about that error with this search `[entity-framework] "Unexpected connection state. When using a wrapping provider ensure that the StateChange event is implemented on the wrapped DbConnection"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated mysql.data and changed the web.config accordingly and it worked like a charm.